# confidence interval for the data itself using lmfit in python

Tags: python, numpy, curve-fitting, lmfit

[image]

Here is the link for the LMFIT implementation of the confidence intervals of parameters: http://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/confidence.html
Here is the code I am using:

```
import lmfit
import numpy as np

# x = np.linspace(1, 10, 250)
# np.random.seed(0)
# y = 1. -np.exp(-(x)/10.) +  0.1*np.random.randn(len(x))

pars = lmfit.Parameters()
pars.add_many(('n', 1.),  ('tau', 3.))

# def residual(pars,data=None):
def residual(pars):
    v = pars.valuesdict()
    # if data is None:
    #     return 1.0 - np.exp(-(x**v['n'])/v['tau'])
    return 1.0 - np.exp(-(x**v['n'])/v['tau'])-y

# create Minimizer
mini = lmfit.Minimizer(residual, pars)

# first solve with Nelder-Mead
out1 = mini.minimize(method='Nelder')

out2 = mini.minimize(method='leastsq', params=out1.params)

lmfit.report_fit(out2.params, min_correl=0.5)

ci, trace = lmfit.conf_interval(mini, out2, sigmas=[0.95],
                                trace=True, verbose=False)
lmfit.printfuncs.report_ci(ci)
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question? The first part of the text is cut; the second part is impossible to read, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit difficult to understand the title *Confidence interval for the data itself using lmfit in python* (there is no data), or the the first sentence *I am doing curve fitting using lmfit package* (you need data to fit).

I think what you are asking for is a way to get extreme values for the model function that best matches your data.  If so, would it work to evaluate your function with all combinations of parameter values `best +/- delta` (where `delta` could be any uncertainly level you like), and take the extreme values of the model function?   That's not very automated, but shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: He is looking for confidence bands: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_and_prediction_bands.